# Avoid flooding disk by copying to failed mount point

Tags: mount, kubuntu, backup, samba, fstab

I intend to copy files from one Kubuntu PC to the Samba share of a second PC as a backup. For this purpose I am using a backup GUI tool.

I would like to mount the samba share to a mount point on the source system (e.g. using /etc/fstab or eventually using a command line). This is not too difficult.

However what happens if the other PC isn't available? The mount point then would be a plain folder and I would flood my small local disk with backup files instead of copying to the remote share.

This once happened to me with an unavailable local disk. However with a second system this accident is much more likely.

How can I prevent that disaster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could solve this by removing any writing rights from the dummy mount point folder. This way, copying files fails if mounting was not successful. For changing the access rights I used Dolphin's context menu.

Comment: Be careful, though, as mounting `ext2/3/4` filesystems seems to use these permissions, which will break your setup.

Comment: Better would be to mount a `tmpfs` filesystem on the mountpoint with options `-o size=64,...`. By mounting as `tmpfs` it bypasses the disk, and by limiting the size of the mountpoint, files will not take up memory/swap when mounting the real filesystem fails. Then you can still own the directory with proper permissions.

Answer (score 1):

I asked a very similar question on serverfault some years ago: https://serverfault.com/q/337602/14942.

There are 5 ways that I thought of, with some additional variations left as an exercise for the reader.

Choices, assuming the backup filesystem is to be mounted at /mnt/backups:

1. Monitor /mnt/backups and ensure it's not root. Perhaps a cron job.
2. Move the mount point into a smaller separately mounted filesystem. Use /mnt/protected/backups instead, and mount /protected first to a small filesystem, perhaps a loop mount to a local file so it is much less likely to fail.
3. Chmod a-rwx /mnt/backups (the root filesystem mount point). (This is the currently accepted answer.)
4. On the mounted tree create a directory called "Backups", then soft link `ln - s /mnt/backup/Backups /Backups`. Using /Backups for backups will fail unless the /mnt/backup is mounted, since the local tree doesn't contain the sub-directory.
5. Performing a check that the directory is correctly mounted in the backup script. (something like `mountpoint -q /mnt/backups || mount /mnt/backups || exit`)